# Playwright: evaluate methode returns Node JSON

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, playwright, webautomation

I tried to get Array from elements in JSON format.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs margin-right active"><i class="fal fa-eye"</i>Icon</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs margin-right active"></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs margin-right active"></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs margin-right active"></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs margin-right active"></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs margin-right active"></button>
```

The response I expected here should be an array of 6 elements like [Icon, ...]

But what I received was:

-{"result":{"0":"ref: ","1":"ref: ","2":"ref: ","3":"ref: ","4":"ref: ","5":"ref: "}}

Function looks following:

```
async evaluateTest(): Promise<any> {
const result = await this.page?.evaluate(() => {return {result:document.querySelectorAll('.menu-visible-columns .btn-xs')}} );
this.debugLog(String(result));
const  res2 = JSON.stringify(result)
return res2;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can only evaluate elements on the browser side.
You can return the array of elements using an `evaluateHandle`, but then you need to use `evaluate` to process that array. e.g.

```
const links = await page.evaluateHandle(() =>
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a"))
  );
console.log(await links.evaluate((links) => links.map((link) => link.text)));
```